# Class based AWS lambda in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a class based AWS lambda function in python called **requestHandler.py** as below

```
from action_dispatcher import ActionDispatcher

class RequestHandler(ActionDispatcher):


    @staticmethod
    def createTemplate(event, context):
        return "Hello world"
```

My **action_dispatcher.py** is as shown below.

```
import json

class ActionDispatcher(object):

    def __call__(self, event, context, *args, **kwargs):

        action = event.get('action')
        handler = getattr(self, action, None)

        if handler is None:
            return json.loads({'status': 'error', 'code': 404, 'message':"Action {0} not found.".format(action) })

        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

With this above setup and lambda handler as **requestHandler.RequestHandler**, i get error **"RequestHandler() takes no arguments"** in this case i create action as createTemplate. so i want to call this method from RequestHandler.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are trying to call your class instead of an instance of the class. `RequestHandler()` will call the `__init__` method to initialize an instance of the class. Since you haven't defined the method it doesn't take any arguments. To access `__call__` you need to call an *instance* of your class.

```
handler = RequestHandler()
result = handler(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is with respect to AWS lambda invoking, so need suggestion based on that

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much (or anything) about AWS. Your error message looks like you are trying to instantiate the `RequestHandler` with arguments instead of call an instance, which Python won't allow with your current code. Could you post the line of code where the call is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can only define a handler in python using `def handler(event, context):`. However, I found [a package that allows you to call the handler as a class](https://pypi.org/project/aws-lambda-handler/)

Usage, as noted in their documentation, is as follows:

`pip install aws-lambda-handler`

```
import aws_lambda

class EchoHandler(aws_lambda.Handler):
    """Echo handler."""

    def perform(self, request, **k):
        """Echo perform method."""
        response = aws_lambda.Response()
        response.body = self.request.event
        return response

echo_handler = EchoHandler()

# `echo_handler` is now a callable function you can map your AWS Lambda function to
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was simple, as mentioned by jacinator, i should try with class instance.
earlier for lambda handler, i used pass class as handler, now i am passing the instance of the class as handler.
Added the line in  **requestHandler.py** `rhandler = RequestHandler()`
So previously my lambda handler was like  `requestHandler.RequestHandler`, now it has been changed to `requestHandler.rhandler`.